# Illustrator Blob Brush Problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

I can't normally apply the custom brush while using blob brush tool.

It's not dependent upon type of brush I use.

With simple brush tool everything is just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The **Blob Brush Tool** creates **shapes**, *not* stroked paths.
- The **Brush Tool** creates stroked **paths**, *not* shapes.

They inherently create artwork which is *constructed differently.*

If you draw with the Blob Brush Tool, then apply a brush stroke, you are applying the brush stroke to the *circumference* of the **shape**. Similarly to applying a brush stroke to a rectangle... the path around the shape gets stroked.

The Blob Brush tool is meant to draw just "blobs" and **not** be a "live" brush path. If you want a live brush path, draw with a standard brush. The Blob Brush is *really* merely a **Calligraphy brush** that gets *expended* when you let go of the mouse. It is 100% possible to *never* use the Blob Brush tool and get *exactly* the same artwork via a Calligraphic brush and the normal Brush tool.